# Google Places gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-places-api

I am trying to use the next page token from the first page results that are retrieved by the call to the Google Places, using the following code:

```
   def pins_in_area
            @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new('api_key_XXXXX')
            @results = @client.spots(params[:lat], params[:long], :radius => params[:radius])
            puts @results
            next_page_token = @results.last.nextpagetoken
            puts next_page_token #spots_by_pagetoken
            next_spots = @client.spots_by_pagetoken(next_page_token)
            puts next_spots
```

...
        end

But, I encounter the following error, not sure why:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 258ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

GooglePlaces::InvalidRequestError (GooglePlaces::InvalidRequestError):
  app/controllers/api/v1/pins_controller.rb:89:in `pins_in_area'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (13.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (35.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (101.1ms)
```

Comment: You should look at the content of params[:lat], params[:long] and params[:radius]. One or more of them may be wrong type or nil.

Comment: Thank you for your help ! The codes executes okau until the following line: next_spots = @client.spots_by_pagetoken(next_page_token). I can get the results and next_page_token, but somehow spots_by_pagetoken(next_page_token) fails.

Comment: What s the output of "puts next_page_token"?

Comment: It is something like: CoQC8wAAAMa-UPK2AUTrpuNKpwxHzsbyVBFVHmqlW9T8KRvMrJ020V4Lv_bfXX6k2EzCrviga7lpBZdZxFWivA_ki8GUp9d9DxoGq1dfkiXFRz57Pb0NdumxVQRQ76KZuDPdFmNKAYlKFrc724VlfoSOqCExH4xQQDf4AMaR4KkEDeg-qA0Fg5O3hOTjpKDvJJomunOq_-ZFg_DUxRl_pU-oYEA_JgHLgldhmTWijkEge4G_iPrdn2tm1rYwLb9QTx2jTK-JKkMt1PBAY6BlkSTBJ9RwAzAdHKVU6a69dS_Npw_wCLP793l_KPzV35zZFc7WnKRpszebIpgTUf9p1pTKd7mmvZYSEHxsKfUWDJZWDhnK8FqbQeEaFI6-ju-6FY-V66SihOQbkfHYx8Wd

Comment: Try to edit your client definition like this: 
 @client = GooglePlaces::Client.new('api_key_XXXXX', {:lat => params[:lat], :lng => params[:long], :radius => params[:radius]})

Comment: I believe @client.spots expects for arguments as well. I get this error: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)):
  app/controllers/api/v1/pins_controller.rb:80:in `pins_in_area'. Where line 80 is: @results = @client.spots

Comment: I checked the definition of spots_by_pagetoken which is depends on:
    def self.list_by_pagetoken(pagetoken, api_key, options = {})
      exclude = options.delete(:exclude) || []
      exclude = [exclude] unless exclude.is_a?(Array)

      options = {
          :pagetoken => pagetoken,
          :key => api_key
      }

      request(:spots_by_pagetoken, false, exclude, options)
    end. Not sure what's wrong :D

Comment: There's a similar bug describe here and a potential solution (in the first post at top).  Try adding the "multipage: true" somewhere. I can't do much :s

https://github.com/qpowell/google_places/issues/70